# What are the paramaters for 2D convolution to generate 768x1024 images with GANs?

Tags: conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network, discriminator

I ams trying to generate synthetic 768x1024 images with GANs (based on 768x1024 images) and there is a problem between the shapes of logits and labels, which I beleive has something to do with the architechture of the network.

```
def define_generator(image_shape=(768,1024,3)):
    # weight initialization
    init = RandomNormal(stddev=0.02,seed=seed)
    # image input
    in_image = Input(shape=image_shape)
    # encoder model
    e1 = define_encoder_block(in_image, 64, batchnorm=False)
    e2 = define_encoder_block(e1, 128)
    e3 = define_encoder_block(e2, 256)
    e4 = define_encoder_block(e3, 512)
    e5 = define_encoder_block(e4, 512)
    e6 = define_encoder_block(e5, 512)
    e7 = define_encoder_block(e6, 512)
    # bottleneck, no batch norm and relu
    b = Conv2D(512, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same', kernel_initializer=init)(e7)
    b = Activation('relu')(b)
    # decoder model
    d1 = decoder_block(b, e7, 512)
    d2 = decoder_block(d1, e6, 512)
    d3 = decoder_block(d2, e5, 512)
    d4 = decoder_block(d3, e4, 512, dropout=False)
    d5 = decoder_block(d4, e3, 256, dropout=False)
    d6 = decoder_block(d5, e2, 128, dropout=False)
    d7 = decoder_block(d6, e1, 64, dropout=False)
    # output
    g = Conv2DTranspose(3, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same', kernel_initializer=init)(d7)
    out_image = Activation('tanh')(g)

    # define model
    model = Model(in_image, out_image)
    return model

# define the discriminator model
def define_discriminator(image_shape):
    # weight initialization
    init = RandomNormal(stddev=0.02,seed=seed)
    # source image input
    in_src_image = Input(shape=image_shape)
    # target image input
    in_target_image = Input(shape=image_shape)
    # concatenate images channel-wise
    merged = Concatenate()([in_src_image, in_target_image])
    # C64
    d = Conv2D(64, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same', kernel_initializer=init)(merged)
    d = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d)
    # C128
    d = Conv2D(128, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same', kernel_initializer=init)(d)
    d = BatchNormalization()(d)
    d = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d)
    # C256
    d = Conv2D(256, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same', kernel_initializer=init)(d)
    d = BatchNormalization()(d)
    d = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d)
    # C512
    d = Conv2D(512, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same', kernel_initializer=init)(d)
    d = BatchNormalization()(d)
    d = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d)
    # second last output layer
    d = Conv2D(512, (4,4), padding='same', kernel_initializer=init)(d)
    d = BatchNormalization()(d)
    d = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d)
    # patch output
    d = Conv2D(1, (4,4), padding='same', kernel_initializer=init)(d)
    patch_out = Activation('sigmoid')(d)
    # define model
    model = Model([in_src_image, in_target_image], patch_out)
    # compile model
    opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.0002, beta_1=0.5)
    model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True), optimizer=opt, loss_weights=[0.5])
    return model




def define_encoder_block(layer_in, n_filters, batchnorm=True):
    # weight initialization
    init = RandomNormal(stddev=0.02,seed=seed)
    # add downsampling layer
    g = Conv2D(n_filters, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same', kernel_initializer=init)(layer_in)
    # conditionally add batch normalization
    if batchnorm:
        g = BatchNormalization()(g, training=True)
    # leaky relu activation
    g = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(g)
    return g

# define a decoder block
def decoder_block(layer_in, skip_in, n_filters, dropout=True):
    # weight initialization
    init = RandomNormal(stddev=0.02,seed=seed)
    # add upsampling layer
    g = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same', kernel_initializer=init)(layer_in)
    # add batch normalization
    g = BatchNormalization()(g, training=True)
    # conditionally add dropout
    if dropout:
        g = Dropout(0.5)(g, training=True)
    # merge with skip connection
    g = Concatenate()([g, skip_in])
    # relu activation
    g = Activation('relu')(g)
    return g



def define_encoder_block(layer_in, n_filters, batchnorm=True):
    # weight initialization
    init = RandomNormal(stddev=0.02,seed=seed)
    # add downsampling layer
    g = Conv2D(n_filters, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same', kernel_initializer=init)(layer_in)
    # conditionally add batch normalization
    if batchnorm:
        g = BatchNormalization()(g, training=True)
    # leaky relu activation
    g = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(g)
    return g

# define a decoder block
def decoder_block(layer_in, skip_in, n_filters, dropout=True):
    # weight initialization
    init = RandomNormal(stddev=0.02,seed=seed)
    # add upsampling layer
    g = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same', kernel_initializer=init)(layer_in)
    # add batch normalization
    g = BatchNormalization()(g, training=True)
    # conditionally add dropout
    if dropout:
        g = Dropout(0.5)(g, training=True)
    # merge with skip connection
    g = Concatenate()([g, skip_in])
    # relu activation
    g = Activation('relu')(g)
    return g
```

I wad wondering how I would change the architechture (assuming that's the way to go), to make it work. I am getting the following error :
`ValueError:` logits`and`labels `must have the same shape, received ((1, 48, 64, 1) vs (1, 48, 48, 1)).`
I tried changing the parameters, but I ams still struggling with it.